# Can we execute code after the return statement in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, return

Hi I am very new in python. It may be silly question. I just want to know can we run the lines which is written after the return statement in python?

Example:

```
def temp1():
    try:
        str1 = 'abcd'
        return str1
        time.sleep(50)
        print('xyz')
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)

def temp2():
    try:
        str2 = temp1()
        print(str2)
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)


temp2()
```

I just want to know after return the value how can I print - xyz?

Comment: No, that's the significance of the `return` statement. However, you could wrap a code block in a context manager, which performs actions before/after entering/exiting the block, but I don't think that's really what you're looking for.

Comment: Hi @PeterWood, thank for the response. Can you tell me the block code which you are discussing?

Comment: Store the variable `str1` and do everything you want to do, and then return the value in the end of the function instead. `return` means to exit the function, so there's no way to continue running code after it.

Comment: @ShivikaPatel have you searched for [python context manager](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+context+manager)?

Comment: Also, the answer below makes a good point about using `finally`, which I forgot about!

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to do that. It's to use try/except/finally.

> If the try statement reaches a break, continue or return statement,
> the finally clause will execute just prior to the break, continue or
> return statement’s execution.

See official [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions).

But I think this is not what you are really looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
import time


def temp1():
    try:
        str1 = 'abcd'
        return str1

    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)

    finally:
        time.sleep(5)
        print('xyz')


def temp2():
    try:
        str2 = temp1()
        print(str2)

    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)


temp2()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).